# SELECT FROM 2 different tables but related data

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have the following code

```
<?php

require_once('db_connection.php');
$return_arr = array();

$param = $_GET["term"];

$query = "SELECT *
            FROM exp_weblog_data,exp_weblog_titles WHERE field_id_5
            LIKE '%". $param ."%'
            LIMIT 50";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $row_array['jItemCode']             = $row['field_id_5'];
    $row_array['jItemDesc']             = $row['title'];
   /* $row_array['jItemWholesale']        = $row['itemWholesale'];
    $row_array['jItemRetail']           = $row['itemRetail'];
    $row_array['jItemPrice']            = $row['itemPrice'];
    $row_array['jQtyOnHand']            = $row['qtyOnHand'];*/

    array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
}


$result->free_result();
$mysqli->close();

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

**I have two tables. "exp_weblog_data" and "exp_weblog_titles". Each table has "entry_id". When I use "field_id_5" from "exp_weblog_data" to start the autosuggest I need to pull additional information from the "exp_weblog_titles" table**

This is for an auto complete query. I need to pull related data from "title" in another table in the same database can someone please help  I know the problem lies with my query but I have tried all kinds of syntax with  JOINS and UNIONS and LEFT JOINS what have you.  Can someone please help me

Comment: Personally, [I always defer to Mr. Atwood when it comes to joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: please explain your tables structure

Comment: Really can't help you unless we know the structure of the tables: what keys relate them, and which tables contain `field_id_5` and `title` for example.

Comment: The table structure is from an expression engine installation if that helps

Comment: What are the fields names from the other table, and is there a field in your current one that it matches with?

Comment: I have two tables.  "exp_weblog_data" and "exp_weblog_titles".  Each table has "entry_id".  When I use "field_id_5" from "exp_weblog_data" to start the autosuggest I need to pull additional information from the "exp_weblog_titles" table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work this way

```
$query = "SELECT field_id_5, exp_weblog_titles.title, field_id_57  
          FROM exp_weblog_data, exp_weblog_titles 
          WHERE exp_weblog_titles.entry_id = exp_weblog_data.entry_id AND            field_id_5
          LIKE '%". $param ."%'
          LIMIT 10";
```

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN clause. You can with one request get related data from 2 or more tables.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html